# Remove letter from an ArrayList of letters each time it is found in input of user

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm working on an Android app which the user can can find hidden letters in a game. These letters are added to an ArrayList. The letters are displayed and the user can enter a 5 letter word using the letters they have available. My issue is when a letter is used I want it to be removed from the arraylist so that the user can't use it again. for example. the user has collected these letters :
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T V U W X Y Z
he enters the word minis. This will not be accepted since it uses 'i' twice and the user has only one 'i' available. I would like it for example on each iteration to remove each letter used. My code for that part is below. The counter is used to see if the word is valid or not.

```
 public void checkValidWord(){

        for(int i = 0; i < answerWord.length(); i++){
            for(Character letter: LettersCollected){
                if(answerWord.charAt(i) == letter){
                    LettersCollected.remove(answerWord.charAt(i));
                    counter ++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(counter == 5){
//            for(int i = 0; i<answerWord.length(); i++){
//                LettersCollected.remove(answerWord.charAt(i));
//            }
            calculateScore();
        }else{
            //Display error message that user does not have letter used available
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: so my issue is how can I remove each letter used in the user's input from the arraylist of available words so that he can't use it twice. My code currently crashes. So on each iteration where a letter in the input is checked against the available letters I want the letter used removed from arraylist of available letters

Comment: The user should only be able to use a letter twice if it appears twice in the arraylist of available letters

Comment: So this is more of a logic question, since you mentioned that a letter can be show up multiple times then it might be better to use a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` where you can store each letter, and the amount of times it's available, then as you read through the word you can decrement the value. If it's 0, you can display your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting ConcurrentModificationException exception?

Assuming that LettersCollected is

```
List<Character>  or  ArrayList<Character>
```

The for-each loop you are using internally uses iterator to go over the list and you are removing the matched *character* using the remove method on the List.
From JavaDoc for [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) , any concurrent modification to the list while iterating over the elements would result in ConcurrentModificationException.
To fix this you can use Iterator.

```
Iterator<Character> itr=LettersCollected.iterator()
while(itr.hasNext()){
     Character letter=itr.next()
     if(answerWord.charAt(i) == letter){
      itr.remove();
   }
}
```

Also try changing variable name "LettersCollected" to "lettersCollected" for better naming standard

Answer (score 0):

Use this on

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int  after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (LettersCollected.contains(s.charAt(s.lenght()-1)))
                   LettersCollected.remove(s.charAt(s.lenght()-1))
                else {
                   // Display error message
                   }
                if (s.lenght() == 5) 
                showResult();
            }
        });
```